# Using Guzzle to consume SOAP

Tags: soap, guzzle

I'm loving the Guzzle framework that I just discovered. I'm using it to aggregate data across multiple API's using different response structures. It's worked find with JSON and XML, but one the services i need to consume uses SOAP. Is there a built-in way to consume SOAP services with Guzzle?

Comment: I also would like to get more info on this topic. The Guzzle documentation does not mention anything about .wsdl files or SOAP.

Answer (score 18):

You can get Guzzle to send SOAP requests.
Note that SOAP always has an Envelope, Header and Body.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <NormalXmlGoesHere>
            <Data>Test</Data>
        </NormalXmlGoesHere>
    </soapenv:Body>
```

The first thing I do is build the xml body with SimpleXML:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<NormalXmlGoesHere xmlns="https://api.xyz.com/DataService/"></NormalXmlGoesHere>');
$xml->addChild('Data', 'Test');

// Removing xml declaration node
$customXML = new SimpleXMLElement($xml->asXML());
$dom = dom_import_simplexml($customXML);
$cleanXml = $dom->ownerDocument->saveXML($dom->ownerDocument->documentElement);
```

We then wrap our xml body with the soap envelope, header and body.

```
$soapHeader = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body>';

$soapFooter = '</soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>';

$xmlRequest = $soapheader . $cleanXml . $soapFooter; // Full SOAP Request
```

We then need to find out what our endpoint is in the api docs.

We then build the client in Guzzle:

```
$client = new Client([
    'base_url' => 'https://api.xyz.com',
]);

try {
    $response = $client->post(
    '/DataServiceEndpoint.svc',
        [
            'body'    => $xmlRequest,
            'headers' => [
            'Content-Type' => 'text/xml',
            'SOAPAction' => 'https://api.xyz.com/DataService/PostData' // SOAP Method to post to
            ]
        ]
    );

    var_dump($response);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception:' . $e->getMessage();
}

if ($response->getStatusCode() === 200) {
    // Success!
    $xmlResponse = simplexml_load_string($response->getBody()); // Convert response into object for easier parsing
} else {
    echo 'Response Failure !!!';
}
```

Answer (score 5):

IMHO Guzzle doesn't have full SOAP support and works only with HTTP requests.
src/Guzzle/Http/ClientInterface.php  Line:76

```
public function createRequest(                                              
    $method = RequestInterface::GET,                                        
    $uri = null,                                                            
    $headers = null,                                                        
    $body = null,                                                           
    array $options = array()                                                
);
```

Even if SOAP server is configured to negotiate on port 80 I think php SoapClient is more appropriate solution here as it supports WSDL

Comment: I think guzzle now is at version 6. Do you know if they did any changes to  support SOAP?

Answer (score 4):

Old Topic, but as I was searching for the same answer, it seems [async-soap-guzzle](https://github.com/meng-tian/async-soap-guzzle) is doing the job.

Comment: this library making additional API call for eahc request using standard php soap library, Any idea why, can we get rid of that additional api call?

Answer (score 3):

Guzzle HTTP can be used for SOAP requests & works like a charm:

Below is the way I have implemented.

Create variables:

```
    public function __construct(Request $request) {
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->openSoapEnvelope   =   '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">';
    $this->soapHeader         =   '<soap:Header> 
                                    <tem:Authenticate>  
                                        <-- any header data goes here-->
                                    </tem:Authenticate>
                                </soap:Header>';

    $this->closeSoapEnvelope   =   '</soap:Envelope>';
}
```

Create a function to form a soap request.

```
public function generateSoapRequest($soapBody){
    return $this->openSoapEnvelope . $this->soapHeader . $soapBody . $this->closeSoapEnvelope;
}
```

Define a body & call generateSoapRequest method.
e.g:

```
$soapBody           =   '<soap:Body>
                                <tem:GetSomeDetails/>
                          </soap:Body>';

$xmlRequest         =   $this->generateSoapRequest($soapBody); 


$client = new Client();

        $options = [
            'body'    => $xmlRequest,
            'headers' => [
                "Content-Type" => "text/xml",
                "accept" => "*/*",
                "accept-encoding" => "gzip, deflate"
            ]
        ];

        $res = $client->request(
            'POST',
            'http://your-soap-endpoint-url',
            $options
        );

        print_r($res->getBody());
```