# How to parse xml with namespaces and special tags

Tags: php, xml, soap

I am trying to parse an xml string but it seems quiet impossible to get it right the xml file is:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<GetBookableApartmentsResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<GetBookableApartmentsResult>
<xs:schema id="BookableApartments" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
   <xs:element name="BookableApartments" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="Apartment">
               <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                     <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                     <xs:element name="BookingUrl" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                     <xs:element name="BookingUrlMobile" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
               </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
         </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
   <BookableApartments xmlns="">
      <Apartment diffgr:id="Apartment1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
         <Name>10419-0001</Name>
         <BookingUrl>http:/test.com</BookingUrl>
         <BookingUrlMobile></BookingUrlMobile>
      </Apartment>
      <Apartment diffgr:id="Apartment2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
         <Name>10419-0002</Name>
         <BookingUrl>http:test.com</BookingUrl>
         <BookingUrlMobile></BookingUrlMobile>
      </Apartment>
```

I want to get the data from all childs of `BookableApartments` or I want to get `Apartment` data.

I have set the correct namespace I believe:

```
$simpleXml = new \SimpleXmlElement($response);

$simpleXml->registerXPathNamespace('prefix', 'http://tempuri.org/');

$res = $simpleXml->xpath('//prefix:GetBookableApartmentsResponse');

$res = $res[0]->children('urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1');

var_dump($res)exit;
```

but all the time I get the result: `SimpleXMLElement {#957}`

If someone could explain to me how to access those data how is the logic that I need to follow in order to access those data ?

I know I have to set the namesapce but as u can see from xml I have a special tag also: `<diffgr:diffgram` any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you parsing the file manually? This looks like a SOAP service so you should interact with it through PHP's [SOAP class](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus this is the response from guzzle, could u help me and be more specific with that ?

Comment: I am not familiar with Guzzle, check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/19170846/2191572

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I followed that thread and thats where I ended up asking the question I get the response `SimpleXMLElement {#955}` can not even see the object content on dump

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I even tried using `SoapClient` the response its `{943}` litteraly.